# error instalation imagick windows 7

Tags: php, imagick

I have installed:

01.- Install Apache_2.4.4-x86-openssl-1.0.1e. Download Anindya's Blog.

02.- Install PHP 5.6 (5.6.6) V11-X86 Thread Safe. Download Php Oficial Windows.

03.- Install [ImageMagick-6.8.6-8-Q16-x86-dll from:](http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/multimedia/graphics/ImageMagick/binaries/) C:\ImageMagick)

04.- Extract php_imagick-3.2.0RC1-5.6-ts-vc11-x86. Download: http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/

05.- Copy (php_imagick.dll) to c:\Php\Ext

06.- Copy C:\ImageMagick (CORE_RL_*) to c:\Php

07.- Copy C:\ImageMagick (CORE_RL_*) to c:\Apache\Bin

08.- Add extension=/Php/ext/php_imagick.dll to c:\Php\php.ini

09.- Add Variables Entorno. MAGICK_HOME C:\ImageMagick\modules\coders;

10.- Start Apache

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate N 64 Bits.

Comment: Imagick uses some info from ImageMagick when it is compiled. It is designed to run with the same version as it was compiled against. The error you are seeing happens when there is a version mismatch. Those lazy Imagick maintainers really ought to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 64bit

Apache 2.4.12 Win32-VC11

PHP 5.6.5 Win32-VC11 x86

ImageMagick 6.8.0-3Q16-windows-dll

PHP Imagick 3.1.2.5.6-ts-VC11 x86

Imagemagick installed in C:\imagemagick

C:\imagemagick added to windows path

MAGICK_HOME C:\ImageMagick\modules\coders added as system variable

Add or uncomment extension=php_imagick.dll in PHP.ini

Copy php_imagick.dll to C:\PHP\Ext

Restart Apache

This worked for me and I hope it will help others.